# How to add child component to createElement?

Tags: vue.js

I want to add child components in createElement.

I use render function in Vue component.

`render: function(createElement) {`

Create component:

```
      const btn = Vue.component('button-counter', {
        data: function () {
          return {
            count: 0
          }
        },
        template: '<button v-on:click="count++">Счётчик кликов — {{ count }}</button>'
      })
```

Try to add:

```
      return createElement(
        'div',
        {
          class: 'content-article',
        },
        [
          btn
        ]
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `btn` component reference would need to be passed to `createElement` (i.e., `createElement(btn)`); or the component name (i.e., `createElement('button-counter')`):

```js
export default {
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(
        'div',
        {
          class: 'content-article',
        },
        [
          createElement(btn),

          // OR
          createElement('button-counter')
        ]
      )
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJWyWZE?editors=1010)